# Set list of branches matching pattern as output variable in GitHub Actions (yml)

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to create a GitHub action that will output a list of feature/ branches for use in another workflow. My output for this step is always an empty string.

I run this step after running actions/checkout, configuring the git environment, fetching, and traversing to the repo's directory:

```sh
echo ::set-output name=branches::$(git branch --list | grep feature/)
```

However, running this in terminal with the same repo checked out on my machine, I get a list of feature branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `git branch --list` will show you just local branches that you checkout locally.

In GitHub Action checkout action, you are usually checking out just single branch.

To get all branches despite of the checkout methods, you have to use:
`git branch -r` and `grep` that one.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same result. `echo "branches: $(git branch -r --list | grep feature/)"` "branches: "

Comment: also the same with -r omitting --list

Comment: Oops, I deleted the line checking out the repo. That works

Comment: related, Im trying to output the list as an array now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841028/set-output-of-step-as-array