# Set output of step as array

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, github-actions

I'm getting a list of `feature/*` branches from my repository in a GitHub action using:

```sh
echo ::set-output name=branches::$( git branch -r | grep -i "feature/" | sed -e "s/.*origin\///" | tr "\n" " " )
```

However, this list is String output and I need it in a String array so I can use it to call another workflow using the Matrix strategy.

I've tried numerous tactics including:

- wrapping the expression in `()` which results in a syntax error ("unexpected token: `(`")
- using an environment variable which results in an empty string with or without wrapping the expression in `()`
- using a local variable which results in different outcomes depending on how I assign it. In my dev environment, I have 2 feature branches (feature/quality-3 and feature/test-feature)

**using**:

```sh
branches=($( git branch -r | grep -i "feature/" | sed -e "s/.*origin\///" | tr "\n" " " ))
```

**with**:

```sh
echo ::set-output name=branches::${branches[@]} # also ${branches[*]}
```

gives an error with both values: "Unexpected type of value 'feature/quality-3 feature/test_feature', expected type: Sequence."

**with**:

```sh
echo ::set-output name=branches::${branches} # or $branches
```

gives an error with 1 value: "Unexpected type of value 'feature/quality-3', expected type: Sequence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass such data as a JSON between jobs:

Use combination of:

- [toJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson)
- [fromJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson)
  to get your output.

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-returning-a-json-object) is a full example from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have a lot more work to do. I thought I could just pass an array and use it, but looks like it has to be JSON equating to an array of key/value pairs for use in the workflow instead.

Comment: @froggomad Yes, you have to take a detour to JSON and then back. Please check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

As per Grzegorz Krukowski, we need to put the array to JSON and then convert it back. For some reasons, `toJSON` doesn't work and here is what I did:

```
branches=(master dev prod)
JSON="["
for branch in ${branches[@]}; do
    echo $branch
    JSONline="\"$branch\","
    # we don't need to iterate on the same branch over and over, so
    # onnly include it when it wasn't included
    if [[ "$JSON" != *"$JSONline"* ]]; then
        JSON="$JSON$JSONline"
    fi
done

# Remove last "," and add the closing bracket
if [[ $JSON == *, ]]; then
    JSON="${JSON%?}"
fi
JSON="$JSON]"

echo $JSON
echo "branches=$( echo "$JSON" )" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Comment: You can also do it using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), `JSON="[$(echo $branches | sed 's/ /, /g')]"`.